# React native app started crashing on razor pay

Tags: react-native, razorpay

I have updated react native version from 0.67.2 to 0.71.1 and app started crashing on react native razor pay after razor modal get's open

Getting crash on release build on opening razor pay activity

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
You must either set a text or a view
com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkState (Preconditions.java:215)
android.widget.Toast.show (Toast.java:318)
com.facebook.react.modules.toast.ToastModule$1.run (ToastModule.java:60)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:958)
```

crash log errors